# extract date from string in access table

Tags: sql, vba, date, ms-access

I am trying to extract `date` from the below string in access. No Idea how to do it as all are in different format.

```
AT (ALL LOCATION) (XYZ) (15TH FEB10) (some).xlsx
AT) (XYZ) (DEC-15) (bdd).xlsx
(AT SOUTH) (XYZ) (FEB11 TO MAR11) (some).xlsx
(AT) (XYZ) (APR13-DEC13) (some - sky).xlsx
```

Comment: I see more than one date.  Are the dates always in the same place?  How else will they vary? Can you give an example of what it should look like in the end? This isn't a "code writing service", it's more of a place that developers (of any experience level) can bring a *specific* question about a *specific* issue, ***share their existing code*** and explain what's been tried & researched so far, along with thorough examples related data and desired result. See [mcve] and [help/on-topic] as well as [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: The dates canbe at different location in the filename as the name could vary. I had asked the question to know if this is possible by any kind of regex or any other method possible to see if a file name contains a Date in it.

Comment: Are the dates the **only** "words" in the strings that **include numbers**?  Or, are they **always** doing to have one of `JAN`,`FEB`,`MAR`,*`…etc`* in them?  If not, you may be out of luck.  Nothing's going to be able to extract parts of a string that don't follow some sort of pattern.

Comment: Thank you, the date will always be in JAN15 or 15Feb18 format only. I think I will have to do it manually.

Comment: Are the dates the only "words" in the strings that **include numbers**?

Comment: Thank you very much, :) below function gives the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the first occurrence of a string between parenthesis that contains a number:

```
Public Function bracketedWordWithNumber(strIn As String) As String

    Dim arr() As String, x As Integer

    'test for number in parentheses
    If Not strIn Like "*(*#*)*" Then Exit Function

    'remove file extension: everything after last dot '.'
    If InStr(strIn, ".") > 0 Then strIn = Left(strIn, InStrRev(strIn, ".") - 1)

    'remove right parentheses ')'
    strIn = Replace(strIn, ")", "")

    'split into array on left parentheses '('
    arr = Split(strIn, "(")

    'iterate array
    For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
        'find strings with numbers
        If arr(x) Like "*#*" Then
            'return match
            bracketedWordWithNumber = arr(x)
            'stop after the first match
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next x

End Function
```

---

## More Information:

- MSDN : **[Split Function (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function)**
- Microsoft.com : **[Like Operator (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator)**
- MSDN : **[InStr Function (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function)**
- MSDN : **[Replace Function (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/replace-function)**